# Gear icon is missing?

Tags: icons

My gear icon is missing? How can I restore it?
I'm using unity on raring.

[image]

Comment: I think this has something to do with installation problems. Can you mouse over it and see if it gives some information? Can you do `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install -f`, and see if they give any errors?

Comment: Hovering mouse doesn't give me anything, wait a minute I'll try these command.

Comment: @Alaa 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. No error.